How to direct all minicom/tmux output to journald
Minicom/tmux can be accessed by a user on the command line, but the content on the screen will get replaced by later content, and the old content is no longer accessible. There's also no logging of timestamps, which journalctl provides. The command:
tmux pipe-pane -o 'cat >>~/tmux.log'

can be used to send output to a log file, but it's not journald and won't have those timestamps. When I try having a service process just call minicom and then attach a tmux session, journalctl contains some output, but like this:

Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: [6B blob data]


Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: Welcome to minicom 2.7.1


Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: OPTIONS: I18n


Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: Compiled on Aug 13 2017, 15:25:34.


Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: Port /dev/ttyACM0


Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys Jul 25 16:08:29 raspberrypi minicom-monitor.sh[2279]: [6B blob data]

If I add "--output cat", then the "blob data" gets replaced with content like "ESC[0mESC[10mESC[HESC[J" (content that got intermixed with readable content on tmux.log when I piped to there), but there's still none of the readable information I get from minicom if I access it on the console. I would have assumed this was a known use case, but haven't found an example of it being done.

What exactly are you trying to achieve ? You want the system journal to contain the tmux session with all the output commands writte to the screen ?

Yeah, log all the tmux output.

I was able to make progress by selecting the device used for the minicom:
TMUX_PANE=$( sudo tmux list-panes | sed 's/:.*//') MINICOM_CONFIG="/etc/minicom/minirc.dfl" if [[ -f $MINICOM_CONFIG ]] then  DEVICE=$(cat /etc/minicom/minirc.dfl | sed -n -e 's/.*dev\///p') fi sudo tmux pipe-pane -o -t ${TMUX_PANE} "cat /dev/${DEVICE} >> tmux.log
However, the output sometimes appears to be mangled, as if the bytes/characters are getting translated incorrectly.

The mangling appeared to be in the tmux/minicom data even prior to logging it. I'll now consider this resolved.

Use systemd-cat: it will direct all output directly to the systemd journal.
For example, given a simple script:
array=('line1' 'line2 foo bar' 'line3' 'done')
for a in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo "$a"
    sleep 1
done

in one terminal window run:
journalctl -f

and in another one run:
bash test.sh | systemd-cat

You will see each line echoed directly into the journal, one per second. It may be useful to prefix each line with a tag for easy identification. You can use sed for this:
bash test.sh | sed -u 's/^/TMUX: /' | systemd-cat

That will produce output like this:
Aug 04 23:18:17 hostname cat[6350]: TMUX: line1
Aug 04 23:18:18 hostname cat[6350]: TMUX: line2 foo bar
Aug 04 23:18:19 hostname cat[6350]: TMUX: line3
Aug 04 23:18:20 hostname cat[6350]: TMUX: done

Now, I haven't tried this with minicom, but using your example I think you could to this:
tmux pipe-pane -o 'sed -u "s/^/TMUX: /" | systemd-cat'


I tried that, and didn't see any lines prepended by "TMUX" or containing the sorts of content I'd expect in journalctl.

I have no other suggestions. You asked how to cat to journald instead of a file, and systemd-cat does exactly that. The sed bit is optional. You'll have to play with it yourself until it does what you want, beyond what is stated in your question.

You also asked about the ANSI escape sequences (ESC etc) which is a different question than how to get things into journald. Get the journald log working first, then worry about filtering/modifying the stream.

It's possible there's an issue with tmux having split panes, and perhaps only one pane is being piped, while the content I want to preserve is in a different pane. However, I've tried using "-t" to specify a pane index, and that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The code I posted here wound up working:
TMUX_PANE=$( sudo tmux list-panes | sed 's/:.*//')
MINICOM_CONFIG="/etc/minicom/minirc.dfl"
if [[ -f $MINICOM_CONFIG ]]
    then  DEVICE=$(cat /etc/minicom/minirc.dfl | sed -n -e 's/.*dev\///p')
fi
sudo tmux pipe-pane -o -t ${TMUX_PANE} "cat /dev/${DEVICE} >> tmux.log

